# CSS Style a child div but only if parent has a following sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to add the `margin-top` style to `.three`, but only if `.one` has a `.two`.

```css
.one {
  background: indianred;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.three {
  background: bisque;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.one .two + .three {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">hello</div>
</div>
<div class="three">there</div>


<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="three">there</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9vuLoLj/)

Can this be done? Appreciate the help.

Comment: This is not possible with CSS alone, but would be trivial using JavaScript.

Comment: CSS cannot go parent. So this is not possible with pure CSS.

Comment: One day with [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) it'll be possible :P

Comment: Yea, technically it would be: `.one:has(.two) + .three`

Comment: @PraveenKumar @Vucko Yes and no. `:has` will only be implemented in JavaScript, and not in CSS. This is due to the way the CSS parser works. For the curious, check out [this post](https://discourse.wicg.io/t/implementation-can-we-push-browser-vendors-to-implement-has/2047/4) I made a few months ago (with my ignorance at the time).

Comment: @jhpratt: Work on :has() has pretty much been put on hold. No one knows if or when it's ever coming to JS, let alone CSS (for which the last discussion suggested bringing it to CSS in limited form which would satisfy 99% of these use cases).

Comment: @BoltClock I'm well aware. Just bringing it up for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the closest you can currently get is reversing the logic and using `:empty`.  It's a poor substitute and probably won't work for your needs, but it *can* work - under the right circumstances.

```css
.one {
  background: indianred;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.three {
  background: bisque;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.one:empty + .three {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">hello</div>
</div>
<div class="three">there</div>


<div class="one"></div><!-- Note how .one is completely empty with not even a newline -->
<div class="three">there</div>
```

This is sort of cheating though, as it's not checking to see if `.one` has `.two`.  Instead it's assuming that `.one` does have a child and that child is `.two`.  If `.one` doesn't have a child, then no margin is applied.  This is making a lot of assumptions and is useless most of the time, unless you can make those same assumptions.

The only way you could use this is if you know that `.two` is the only possible child and that if `.one` doesn't have `.two` then it will always have nothing.  No spaces, newlines, or anything else that can be counted as a child (comments are safe).

A good way to see if you can use this (or something similar) is to try to rewrite your logic.  If 'Add margin-top to `.three`, but only if `.one` has a `.two`' can be rewritten as 'Remove margin-top from `.three`, but only if `.one` is empty' then this method will work.  Depending on what you actually need, there may be other ways to rethink your logic into something currently doable.